# How do I make a view block with picture of the currently logged-in user?

Tags: views

How do I make a view block with picture of the currently logged-in user?
I am using Drupal 8.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new view `/admin/structure/views`.

[image]

2. Add  a contextual filter in view: `User: User ID` and configure.

[image]

3. Add picture field.
4. Save.
5. Show block where you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the 'Picture' field of user, create your view like this.

1. Goto /admin/structure/views/add
2. View settings

   - Show -> Users
3. Block settings

   - Create a block
4. Save and Edit
5. Add field 'Picture'
6. Click on 'ADVANCED' and add 'Contextual filters'

   - Add 'User ID'
     -> Provide default value -> Use ID from logged in user
     -> Apply
7. Save and add your bloc to the page.

You can also do it programmatically like : http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/107/create-a-simple-block-programmatically
Then use following codes to get the image.

```
$userCurrent = \Drupal::currentUser(); 
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($userCurrent->id()); 
$output[] = $user->get('user_picture')->first()->view(); 
return $output;
```